# How can I make shell autocomplete the beginning of a filepath?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, autocomplete

I have a project with a deeply nested folder structure. Most of the time I know the name of the file I want to work with, but the folder path is too long/complicated to type when I want to edit it, like:

```
vim folder/is/deep/down/there/myfile.js
```

Is there a way to make the shell auto populate the path for me if the filename is unique, with something like:

```
vim *myfile.js
```

press <kbd>tab</kbd>

```
vim folder/is/deep/down/there/myfile.js
```

I mostly use bash, but I’m fine with zsh if it can solve the problem.

Comment: workaround: what about `mypath=folder/is/deep/down/there/`, `vim $mypath/myfile.js`? And yes, check out zsh GLOB_COMPLETE as recommended on SO.

Comment: Thanks @meatspace, this would work fine for a few folders but the project I'm working on has tens of different paths. Naming and remembering all of them would not be feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zsh, you can use the `**` operator to do this:

```
vim **/myfile.js
```

Then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and zsh will recursively search for the `myfile.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash 4 and higher you can also use the `**` operator for globbing (to fetch file names) and for tab completion (similarly to [the zsh answer from Heptite](https://superuser.com/a/873269/32696)).

I'm unaware of when tab completions for `**` were added to Bash (likely 4.0), or even if they are standard, but they are working for me in 4.3.11 (on Lubuntu). They appear to be activated by default.

However, the behaviour of `**` for globbing is not activated by default, and requires that you set the `globstar` option using `shopt`. That is to say, execute `shopt -s globstar` somewhere before you attempt to use `**` in a globbing pattern (most likely in your `.bashrc`). It is worth pointing out that activating `globstar` may interefere with your tab completion when there are multiple matches. I discovered this in a quick test.